# How to enable cloud debugger for python flask app on Cloud Run

Tags: python, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-debugger

I am trying to enable Google Cloud Debugger for a Flask app that I am running in Cloud Run.

The project is a simple "Hello World" with Flask and Dockerfile.  The code is synced for Bitbucket to Cloud Source Repositories and set to trigger launch on master branch update.

Everything is working as expected, with new pushes triggering a successful build. Now, though, I want to add Cloud Debugger and have hit some problems.

Following the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/setup/python?authuser=2#cloud-run), I have:

- Enabled Cloud Debugger API
- Added `pip install google-python-cloud-debugger`to my Dockerfile
- Added the following code early in my application

```
try:
  import googleclouddebugger
  googleclouddebugger.enable(
    breakpoint_enable_canary=True
  )

except ImportError:
  pass
```

I pushed the changes and the build was successful.

I can see that the Cloud Repository is showing the right commit, but when I look under debugger, no applications are visible (screen shot 1 below) and if I click "start debugging" in Cloud Source Repo, I get a message saying that I need to setup Debugger (screenshot 2)

Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

[image]

[image]

Comment: which version of python you have? which cloud debugger version you have installed?

Comment: Did you deployed the `source-context.json` file https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/source-context#python

Comment: what distro is your dockerfile using? alpine is listed as trouble on git for python-debugger.

Comment: @Pentium10. Thank you such clear comments. I have python 3.7 running at the moment. I downgraded from 3.9 as I found conflicting advice on what was needed.  I am using the Slim distro.  I haven't deployed the source-context.json file, as this was not mentioned in relation to Cloud Run, but I will give that a try next.

Comment: @Pentium10 Adding the source-context.json didn't help.  Maybe I will try a different distro next...Do you have any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the [Service account credentials file](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#command-line) in your application folder:

1. Create a [credentials file](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#creating_a_service_account)
2. Delete your application from the Cloud Run Console
3. Redeploy your app to the Cloud Run
4. If you followed the steps properly, your application should show up on the Debugger page.

The possible cause of the issue is that your app can't communicate with your GCP project due to the lack of authentication.

If it doesn't work, use the link to the application logs that's being provided when deploying the app, and share the logs with the error.

Comment: I believe this is the issue.   But I am not sure how best to update.  When developing locally I have been using "gcloud auth application-default login".  to authorise temporarily with my own credentials.

Comment: Works locally, but whe pushed ot Cloud run I get access permisson issues:  Permission 'cloudbuild.builds.create' denied on ....

Comment: @Finglish I'm not sure if you tried with the credentials file as initially, I was receiving the same error but adding the file fixed it

Comment: I fixed the cloudbuild issue, it was unrelated. I am going to try adding the credentials file, but I am not keen on doing it this way in the long run as storing an unencrypted key file with the code seems like a bad idea.